# Can nerdctl/crictl be used to list containers started by docker

Tags: docker, containerd, nerdctl

I'm using version 20.10.21 of docker, in my understanding [docker with this version uses containerd to manage image and container lifecycle](https://www.docker.com/blog/extending-docker-integration-with-containerd/#:%7E:text=As%20we%20mentioned%20earlier%2C%20Docker,containerd%20into%20the%20Docker%20Engine.), but why cannot I use crictl/nerdctl to list the containers which I started by docker cli?

What I've tried:

1. Check if docker uses containerd to manage contianers, ths is the result of *systemctl status docker*

> ```
>  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine 
>  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
> Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
>          └─http-proxy.conf
>  Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-12-04 22:44:27 CST; 1min 18s ago TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
>    Docs: https://docs.docker.com    Main PID: 1821 (dockerd)
>   Tasks: 91 (limit: 38297)
>  Memory: 229.6M
>     CPU: 1.214s
>  CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
>          ├─1821 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
>          ├─1845 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level info
> ```

I guess this means containerd is started by docker daemon. And the unix socket is located at */var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock*

2. Try nerdctl to list containers but got error message:

> ```
> $ nerdctl --address unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock ps  
> FATA[0000] rootless containerd not running? (hint: use `containerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install` to start rootless  containerd): stat /run/user/1000/containerd-rootless: no such file or directory
> ```

Then I tried it again with *sudo*

> ```
> sudo nerdctl --address  unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock ps  
> CONTAINER ID  IMAGE    COMMAND    CREATED    STATUS    PORTS    NAMES
> ```

As you can see, there's no container listed, but *docker ps* shows many containers I started.

3. Try crictl to check result, but got errors:

> ```
> sudo crictl --r unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock ps
> E1204 22:47:27.190569    3925 remote_runtime.go:557] "ListContainers with filter from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService" filter="&ContainerFilter{Id:,State:&ContainerStateValue{State:CONTAINER_RUNNING,},PodSandboxId:,LabelSelector:map[string]string{},}"
> FATA[0000] listing containers: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
> ```

So my questions is: Why can't I get the same results of docker cli by nerdctl/crictl? Is there anything wrong I've done? or anything wrong in my understanding?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: do you also get the `FATA[0000]...` error for `crictl info`? This would be mentioned in [crictl docs](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/crictl.md#download-and-inspect-a-container-image) and seems to be the containerd config.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the namespace is not specified in your command. Adding `--namespace moby` shows Docker containers. Leaving out the namespace defaults to a namespace named "default".